# Drupal 7 show custom content querying a path

Tags: path, drupal-7, customization

The behaviour I expect from querying, for instance, "http://mydrupalsite.com/customers/1456" in my browser is to open just a normal drupal page with the "body" (not the html < body >, but the page body as in the area where the main information is displayed) code generated by a function to which I passed "1456".

I tried to replicate this behaviour using the hook_menu:

```
$items['customers/%'] = array(
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'mycustomer_render',
    'page arguments' => array(1)
);
```

Where mycustomer_render() will take an argument (which is correctly passed) and generate some code that I want to display in that main area. However, the callback will open a page with **only** the code generated by the function. No sidebar, no header, etc.

Mind you I don't want to display node info or anything, just custom html code generated by the function.

Comment: what does your "mycustomer_render" function look like?

Comment: @mmiles It's something pretty much in the line of 
    `echo "<table>";
    echo htmlDataFromCustomer($arg1);
    echo "</table>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about your callback function:

> It's something pretty much in the line of echo ""; echo
>   htmlDataFromCustomer($arg1); echo "";

You want your callback function to **return** data, not echo it. Echoing data within a callback function will display it immediately to the page and not allow drupal to properly run through the rendering process, hence why you would not see anything else on your page.

To display your content correctly within drupal, your callback function should be something like the following.

```
<?php
function mycustomer_render($arg1){
  return '<table>'.htmlDataFromCustomer($arg1).'</table>';
}
?>
```

If however, you are looking to have just the content of your function output and nothing else, then you should echo your content followed by a [drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7), like so:

```
<?php
function mycustomer_render($arg1){
  echo '<table>',htmlDataFromCustomer($arg1),'</table>';
  drupal_exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. The problem came from my misunderstanding of the way callbacks work. Thank you so much!